# Glitch in reputation points?

Tags: bug, reputation

Today, my question at [Can a substance have zero vapour pressure above absolute zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424837/) had 3 upvotes and [my reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/46757/timothy?tab=reputation) was 597 points. Later it had 4 upvotes and my reputation was 602 points. Later it had 5 upvotes and my reputation was 606 points and when I opened the reputation menu, I saw that it said I gained 10 points and lost 1 point and in total gained 9 points today. I think the loss of a point came from me downvoting an answer. Later, my question had 4 upvotes and my reputation was 601 but the menu still showed me as having earned 9 points today. A bit later before I posted this question. I saw that that question had 5 upvotes and my reputation was 606 points and the menu showed me as having earned 9 points today and the glitch seemed to have gone away.

Edit: Even later long after I posted this question, I saw that my reputation is 604 but it lists me as having earned only 5 points and as having recently lost 4 points so my reputation should be 602 now.

Comment: how's your `/reputation` tab look? It'd be good to see from that log whether your interpretation of where points came from/went to is correct.

Comment: Here is your reputation tab: https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/46757/timothy?tab=reputation&sort=time . It is important to sort your reputation changes by selecting the "time" tab. We can't see everything in it, but you can. Anything what changed your reputation, should be there and visible for you (except a very rare case what had caused -100 reputation loss and in your case it obviously did not happen).

Comment: If you are still unsure, you might consider attaching a screenshot of this list (note, only if it is okay for you to publish the -1 rep change of your answer down).

Comment: @peterh From what I saw even later after I made the edit, I think that there's more of a delay in showing my reputation than in showing the reputation menu.

Comment: @Timothy It is possible, SE has many caching to accelerate its site, and the rep calculation happens is a complex algorithm, taking a lot of resources.